# How to reorder categorical raster legend order in R

Tags: raster, r, visualisation, terra, categorized-renderer

For example, I have a landcover raster and I want to use `terra::plot` to make a map.

```
library(terra)
test <- rast('test.tif')
plot(test)
```

[image]

The order now is "3,4,6,8". Now I want to reorder it to "3,4,8,6"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not include example data/code, but I am assuming this is a categorical raster. Something like this:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
levels(r) <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"))
plot(r)
```

The categories follow the order of the IDs in the attribute table (unless you do `plot(r, sort=TRUE)`). It was not easy to change that, but with terra version 1.5.39 (currently the development version) you can now use the sort argument to change the order

```
plot(r, sort=c( "water", "urban", "forest"))
```

You can install the development version with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71720456/635245) for SpatVector